# Hot code push in react native

Tags: react-native

Yes, Microsoft Code Push is hot now-a-days but my problem is they do not support GitLab which I am using right now to build my mobile app. [React native auto updater](https://github.com/redbooth/react-native-auto-updater) is no longer being maintained.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: "do not support GitLab" in what way should they support Gitlab? What functionality do you expect it to have?

Comment: In order for the code push to work you need to link and push your app to GitHub, BitBucket or Visual Studio Team Services so they can build it . . Right now there is no way or option in their control panel where I can link my GitLab account to Visual Studio App Center.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft Code Push is part of [App Center](https://appcenter.ms/). Github integration is not required to use its over-the-air update feature (which is what `react-native-auto-updater` does).

You can use the [code-push cli](https://github.com/Microsoft/code-push/tree/master/cli) or [appcenter cli](https://github.com/Microsoft/appcenter-cli) to publish your Javascript code to the cloud, and use [react-native-code-push](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push) to retrieve the updates in your RN app.

Alternatively, you can use [Expo](https://expo.io/) which comes with its own OTA functionalities.

Github integration in App Center is only used for automatically building the `.apk` and `.ipa` binaries from the git commits. If you need an automatic binary build tool, you can try [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/), or set up Git hooks to push your code to a private Github repository whenever it's pushed to Gitlab.

Comment: oohhh I see . . that is a great news . . let try to play around more and get back later. Thank you again

Comment: it worked!!! :) you are right about github and other services it is not needed :) thank you so much.